# Create stack to convert from infix to postfix using arrays

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I am currently trying to create my own stack without importing java.util.*. I am only allowed to use arrays and loops to convert my infix expression to postfix for it to work in a calculator. I can already split the infix up into terms but couldn't find any articles explaining how to approach this problem. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: could you describe your problem further please? Maybe add some code or pseudo-code to explain your ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? The general idea would be to create an array and keep track of the top of the stack after any of your stack operations, possibly "growing" the array of the stack if needed.

Comment: actually it sounds like two problems at a time. First you need to create your "Stack" with a simple array. Like for example you could create a class `StackArray` with an array to back your elements. Then you need the methods that a Stack usually has (push, pop, peek...). Once you have your stack implementation you analyse your Infix-postfix-problem. My advice: do it on paper. Once you've split your expression (reading it as "infix") you need to add the "terms" to your Stack in the right order. If you have `arr=['a', '+', 'b']` you do: `stack.put(arr[0]); stack.put(arr[2]);stack.put(arr[1]);`

Comment: The problem is that I understand the principle of the shunting yard algorithm, but I can't find out how to implement it into my code. Right now I have made a new class containing public boolean isEmpty(), public String pop() and public String push() which I will use to replace the stack functions

Comment: not sure, maybe [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) or some of the algorithms linked there (coincidence I tried it out last week, but sure used `java.util`)

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914209/infix-to-postfix-conversion-in-java

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) is a nice description of the algorithm (wikipedia/en).

Basically you start by splitting your expression. For example

```
a + b * c
```

If it where a String, then you do:

```
String expression = "a + b * c";
String[] terms = expression.split(" ");  // this will split the string at every whitespace
```

Now your Array should look like this:  `["a", "+", "b", "*", "c"]`

You now need an array where you can put your "terms" in for the postfix order:

```
String[] postFixTerms = new String[expression.length]; // it should have the same size as the original array
```

So to fill it, you read your `terms` array from left to right, meaning you start at index 0 and end at n. **but** you want to filter out the operands and put them in your Stack!

```
int termsIndex=0;  // you will have two indices because you have two arrays!
for(int i=0; i<terms.length; i++){
   String element = terms[i];
   if(elementIsOperand(element)){
      operandsStack.put(element);
   }else{
      postFixTerms[termsIndex] = element; 
      termsIndex++;
   }
}
```

At this point you should have an array with your "numbers":

```
postFixTerms=["a", "b", "c", null, null]; // remember you only added the numbers in it not the operands, so there is still some space left at the end of the array
```

And you have your operandsStack:

```
operandsStack=["+","*"];
```

Now you only need to put them together, but remember that a stack works "FILA" -first in last out, so:

```
postFixTerms[termsIndex] = operandsStack.pull();  // adds "*" first
termsIndex++;
postFixTerms[termsIndex] = operandsStack.pull();  // then adds the "+"
```

If all goes right, your final postfix expression should be

```
["a","b","c","*","+"];
```

Comment: BTW: the method "elementIsOperand" needs to be implemented by you ;)